# Xcode 6 localizable splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I need use text on splash screen in four different language.

Is any way to localize Launchimage in Xcode 6?

I don't find any good solution.

Comment: use MCLocalization https://github.com/Baglan/MCLocalization

Comment: Check this link : http://www.appcoda.com/localization-tutorial-ios8/  Here they have explained how one can localize images and add diff diff images as per localization language.

Comment: i need help with new version of xcode 6 and launch image

Answer (score 0):

Don't use images.
Use xib files.

```
In project settings general tab: Launch screen file. 
xib can be localized.
```

If you create new project (lets say simple view app) it is done for you. Test it on small test project first.

**Edit:**

**For compatibility with older iOS version 7 and bellow:**

use good old images. Add image to the project (do not use image assets), select image in xcode, open side menu, first tab, you find there localize, hit that button, check all required languages, copy localized copies of image to right folders that were created fro you. You are done. This approach works nicely, but drawback is that many images will increase bundle size user have to download.

Comment: It isn't work on ios 7.0

Comment: you didn't mention that you require iOS7. Anyway, than you have to go with images.